# Mail not sending from web hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sockets, email

I have contact formin my website. Have windows hosting with GoDaddy. When I tested contact from in my localhost it worked & sending mail but in hosting it gives exceptions.

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.130.108:587 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at DynamicPage.sendInquiry_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in G:\PleskVhosts\brandstik.in\httpdocs\DynamicPage.aspx.vb:line 173

```
try {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
    mail.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress(inquiryEmail.Text);
    mail.Subject = "Quote Request For " + quoteID.Text;
    mail.Body = "New Quote request from customer<br /><br/>Customer Name - '" + inquiryName.Text + "' <br />Customer Email - '" + inquiryEmail.Text + "'<br />Customer Contact - '" + inquiryNumber.Text + "'<br />Comment - '" + inquiryMessage.Text + "'";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@doamain.com", "1234567890");
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    Response.Write("Sent");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Your SMTP Server needs to get configured to contact form work.');</script>")
    Response.Write(ex);
}
```

Comment: Contact GoDaddy support and verify the app is not being blocked!

Comment: Refer this:[Gmail SMTP no longer working in Godaddy Server](http://forums.asp.net/t/2094021.aspx?Gmail+SMTP+no+longer+working+in+Godaddy+Server)

Comment: You may need to access your gmail using HTTP instead of SMTP to get around GoDaddy's restrictions. Consider the Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/

Answer (score 0):

Seems they dont allow it. You need to use GoDaddys email relay server. See manual here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-email-using-systemnetmail-19291

Comment: SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com" you mean this is not allowed by GoDaddy?

Comment: right, you would have to use relay-hosting.secureserver.net there

Comment: Are you sure? I f I have to use gmail to send email then too I need to use relay-hosting.secureserver.net ?

Comment: @SUN -- you can probably use their relay server with a Gmail return address, but the messages might be delayed or blocked for certain recipients. Ideally you want to send using an authenticated account.